# How can I animate these divs inside divs?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build a responsive 3 column grid. No problem on that respect. The issue comes because I want to have 2 DIVs with content at the top and bottom of each box. I can't add images, but you can copy and paste the link below if you want to better understand what I mean:

http://i62.tinypic.com/2h2nj4m.jpg

I could have those 2 top and bottom boxes, but, here's the deal:

1. I want top box to be totally hidden on load
2. I want bottom box to be partially hidden on load
3. I want both boxes to show and exchange position on hover, so bottom box will be on top and top box will be on bottom
4. I want both boxes to change color while they change position
5. I want it to work cross browser

So, I worked a lot on the code and I got to this:

```css
#grid {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding: 0 20px
}
#grid li {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 220px;
  margin: 8px;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.cook {
  background: #333 url(images/th1.jpg)
}
.computer {
  background: #555 url(images/th2.jpg)
}
.yoga {
  background: #777 url(images/th3.jpg)
}
.blacktrans {
  transition: 0.8s all ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: 0.8s all ease-in-out;
  z-index: 10000;
  display: block;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  color: #333;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  z-index: 1000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 180px;
}
.blacktrans:hover {
  display: block;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  top: 0;
  height: 80px
}
.salmon {
  transition: 0.8s all ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: 0.8s all ease-in-out;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background: rgba(0, 51, 102, 0.8);
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 24px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -180px;
}
.salmon .price {
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 10px
}
.classbox {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 220px;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.8s all ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: 0.8s all ease-in-out;
  padding-top: 180px;
}
.classbox:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  padding-top: 0;
}
.blacktrans h3 {
  font-size: 20px;
}
.blacktrans h3 a {
  color: #333;
  padding: 0 5px;
}
.classbox .salmon {
  top: 160px;
}
.classbox:hover .blacktrans h3 a {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0 5px;
}
.time {
  color: #3498db;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0 5px;
}
.seemore {
  width: 9px;
  height: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 5px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 1.5s all ease-in-out
}
.classbox:hover > .blacktrans > .seemore {
  opacity: 1;
}
.boxbg {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<!-- START GRID -->
<div id="grid">
  <ul>
    <li class="yoga">
      <div class="classbox">
        <div class="blacktrans">
          <img class="seemore" src="images/arrow_more.png" alt="see more" />
          <h3><a href="view2.html">Yoga Asana</a></h3>

          <p class="time">6:30 @ 7:00 PM</p>
        </div>
        <div class="salmon">
          <p class="price">$20</p>
        </div>
        <div class="boxbg">
          <a href="view2.html">
            <img src="images/classbox.png" alt="" />
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <!-- end item -->
    <li class="computer">
      <div class="classbox">
        <div class="blacktrans">
          <img class="seemore" src="images/arrow_more.png" alt="see more" />
          <h3><a href="view2.html">HTML5 and CSS3 Basics</a></h3>

          <p class="time">4:30 @ 5:30 PM</p>
        </div>
        <div class="salmon">
          <p class="price">$30</p>
        </div>
        <div class="boxbg">
          <a href="view2.html">
            <img src="images/classbox.png" alt="" />
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <!-- end item -->
    <li class="cook">
      <div class="classbox">
        <div class="blacktrans">
          <img class="seemore" src="images/arrow_more.png" alt="see more" />
          <h3><a href="view2.html">Cookin 101</a></h3>

          <p class="time">6:30 @ 7:00 PM</p>
        </div>
        <div class="salmon">
          <p class="price">$40</p>
        </div>
        <div class="boxbg">
          <a href="view2.html">
            <img src="images/classbox.png" alt="" />
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <!-- end item -->
    <li class="yoga">
      <div class="classbox">
        <div class="blacktrans">
          <img class="seemore" src="images/arrow_more.png" alt="see more" />
          <h3><a href="view2.html">Yoga Asana</a></h3>

          <p class="time">6:30 @ 7:00 PM</p>
        </div>
        <div class="salmon">
          <p class="price">$20</p>
        </div>
        <div class="boxbg">
          <a href="view2.html">
            <img src="images/classbox.png" alt="" />
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <!-- end item -->
    <li class="computer">
      <div class="classbox">
        <div class="blacktrans">
          <img class="seemore" src="images/arrow_more.png" alt="see more" />
          <h3><a href="view2.html">HTML5 and CSS3 Basics</a></h3>

          <p class="time">4:30 @ 5:30 PM</p>
        </div>
        <div class="salmon">
          <p class="price">$30</p>
        </div>
        <div class="boxbg">
          <a href="view2.html">
            <img src="images/classbox.png" alt="" />
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <!-- end item -->
    <li class="cook">
      <div class="classbox">
        <div class="blacktrans">
          <img class="seemore" src="images/arrow_more.png" alt="see more" />
          <h3><a href="view2.html">Cookin 101</a></h3>

          <p class="time">6:30 @ 7:00 PM</p>
        </div>
        <div class="salmon">
          <p class="price">$40</p>
        </div>
        <div class="boxbg">
          <a href="view2.html">
            <img src="images/classbox.png" alt="" />
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <!-- end item -->
    <li class="yoga">
      <div class="classbox">
        <div class="blacktrans">
          <img class="seemore" src="images/arrow_more.png" alt="see more" />
          <h3><a href="view2.html">Yoga Asana</a></h3>

          <p class="time">6:30 @ 7:00 PM</p>
        </div>
        <div class="salmon">
          <p class="price">$20</p>
        </div>
        <div class="boxbg">
          <a href="view2.html">
            <img src="images/classbox.png" alt="" />
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <!-- end item -->
    <li class="computer">
      <div class="classbox">
        <div class="blacktrans">
          <img class="seemore" src="images/arrow_more.png" alt="see more" />
          <h3><a href="view2.html">HTML5 and CSS3 Basics</a></h3>

          <p class="time">4:30 @ 5:30 PM</p>
        </div>
        <div class="salmon">
          <p class="price">$30</p>
        </div>
        <div class="boxbg">
          <a href="view2.html">
            <img src="images/classbox.png" alt="" />
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <!-- end item -->
    <li class="cook">
      <div class="classbox">
        <div class="blacktrans">
          <img class="seemore" src="images/arrow_more.png" alt="see more" />
          <h3><a href="view2.html">Cookin 101</a></h3>

          <p class="time">6:30 @ 7:00 PM</p>
        </div>
        <div class="salmon">
          <p class="price">$40</p>
        </div>
        <div class="boxbg">
          <a href="view2.html">
            <img src="images/classbox.png" alt="" />
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <!-- end item -->
    <li class="yoga">
      <div class="classbox">
        <div class="blacktrans">
          <img class="seemore" src="images/arrow_more.png" alt="see more" />
          <h3><a href="view2.html">Yoga Asana</a></h3>

          <p class="time">6:30 @ 7:00 PM</p>
        </div>
        <div class="salmon">
          <p class="price">$20</p>
        </div>
        <div class="boxbg">
          <a href="view2.html">
            <img src="images/classbox.png" alt="" />
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <!-- end item -->
    <li class="computer">
      <div class="classbox">
        <div class="blacktrans">
          <img class="seemore" src="images/arrow_more.png" alt="see more" />
          <h3><a href="view2.html">HTML5 and CSS3 Basics</a></h3>

          <p class="time">4:30 @ 5:30 PM</p>
        </div>
        <div class="salmon">
          <p class="price">$30</p>
        </div>
        <div class="boxbg">
          <a href="view2.html">
            <img src="images/classbox.png" alt="" />
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <!-- end item -->
    <li class="cook">
      <div class="classbox">
        <div class="blacktrans">
          <img class="seemore" src="images/arrow_more.png" alt="see more" />
          <h3><a href="view2.html">Cookin 101</a></h3>

          <p class="time">6:30 @ 7:00 PM</p>
        </div>
        <div class="salmon">
          <p class="price">$40</p>
        </div>
        <div class="boxbg">
          <a href="view2.html">
            <img src="images/classbox.png" alt="" />
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <!-- end item -->
  </ul>
  <hr/>
</div>
<!-- /grid -->
<!-- END GRID -->
```

you can also see it in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1552wga0/).

So, as you can see, it doesn't work. At some point I made one of the boxes work, and then I changed something and couldn't get back. So, I know I'm close, I just can't figure how to continue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not completely sure if I understand the question since it has several parts, but take a look to [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bmcjobby/) and let me know if this is what you were looking for.

As for your code, you're right, you were pretty close, so you don't need to do any changes in your HTML and only a few changes in your CSS, as follows:

```
#grid {
    max-width:1000px;
    margin:20px auto;
    padding:0 20px
}
#grid li {
    display:block;
    width:300px;
    height: 220px;
    margin:10px 8px;
    float:left;
    overflow:hidden;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
}
.cook {
    background:#333 url(images/th1.jpg)
}
.computer {
    background:#555 url(images/th2.jpg)
}
.yoga {
    background:#777 url(images/th3.jpg)
}
.blacktrans {
    transition:0.8s all ease-in-out;
    z-index:10000;
    display:block;
    background:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    color:#333;
    padding:0 5px;
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    z-index:1000;
    position:absolute;
    top:180px;
}
.classbox:hover > .blacktrans {
    display:block;
    background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    top:0;
    height:80px
}
.salmon {
    transition:0.8s all ease-in-out;
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:60px;
    background:rgba(0, 51, 102, 0.8);
    color:#fff;
    font-size:24px;
    position:absolute;
    top:-180px;
}
.salmon .price {
    font-size:24px;
    padding:10px
}
.classbox {
    display:block;
    width:300px;
    height:220px;
    position:relative;
    transition:0.8s all ease-in-out;
    padding-top:180px;
}
.classbox:hover {
    opacity:1;
    padding-top:0;
}
.blacktrans h3 {
    font-size:20px;
    padding:0;
    margin:5px auto;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
.blacktrans h3 a {
    color:#333;
    padding:0 5px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.classbox:hover > .salmon {
    top:160px;
}
.classbox:hover > .blacktrans h3 a {
    color:#fff;
    padding:0 5px;
}
.time {
    color:#3498db;
    font-size:18px;
    text-align:left;
    padding:0 5px;
}
.seemore {
    width:9px;
    height:15px;
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    right:5px;
    opacity:0;
    transition:1.5s all ease-in-out
}
.classbox:hover > .blacktrans > .seemore {
    opacity:1;
}
.boxbg {
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:0;
}
```

The main problem you had is you needed to target the whole `.classbox` element to apply the `:hover` behaviors, so as you can see, I didn't even change your styles (or maybe something trivial), what I did change was the construct. Hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Fabio, this is EXACTLY what I wanted! Thanks a lot!